# Sum on Unique tables

Tags: mysql

I have to produce sum of column B and C based on column A and distinct value of column D.

```
column A | column B | column C | column D
------------------------------------------
A1       | 23       | 33       | unique1
A1       | 73       | 44       | unique2
A1       | 99       | 87       | unique3
A1       | 23       | 33       | unique1
A1       | 56       | 35       | unique4
A1       | 73       | 44       | unique2
```

Now i have to sum column B and C data for column A (A1) but skipping 4th and 6th rows because column D is duplicate.

I have used group by along with SUM but getting 4 rows. I need sum of all "B" and "C" for all the 4 records.

Comment: can you please post your desired output data

Comment: What is the logic for choosing the first over the fourth record, for `unique1` ?

Comment: Since records in databases have no order you need to specify sort order. Any of duplicate rows may be excluded depending on sort order.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Can you remove either the MySQL or SQL Server tag.  They are different products.  Often different solutions are required.

Comment: it's a innodb and no primary key

Comment: logic for choosing the first over the fourth record, for unique1 - Yes and all column will have same value in first and fourth record. I have edited the post to reflect the same

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ought to do such a magic

Comment: DISTINCT gives me multiple rows, my desired output is  - (23 + 33 + 73 + 44 + 99 + 87 + 56 + 35 ) in 1 row only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `comment`

> DISTINCT gives me multiple rows, my desired output is - (23 + 33 + 73
>   + 44 + 99 + 87 + 56 + 35 ) in 1 row only

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(B + C) totalSum
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D
        FROM your_table
    ) t
```

Try this query in this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70164/1/0)

According to mysql documentation:

> DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

**Sample Input:**

[image]

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please check this and let me know if it works for you. @Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
with cte as (
    select A, B, C
    from table1
    group by A, B, C, D
)
select A, sum(B) as sumB, sum(C) as sumC
from cte
group by A
```